# Boostrap delete just a cell

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on a table with bootstrap and I want to hide or remove a cell in this table.

Screen : http://perche.jeremy.free.fr/tab.png (I post link because I can't post the image ^^)
So I want to hide or delete the cell in red, I saw none solution ...

Edit :

```
                    <div class="widget stacked widget-table action-table">
                    <div class="widget-content">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Avant</th>
                            <th>Aujourd'hui</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" class="text-center" style="background-color:#C0C0C0;"><strong>Catégorie 1</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Check1</td>
                            <td>20</td>
                            <td>40</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Check1</td>
                            <td>20</td>
                            <td>40</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" class="text-center" style="background-color:#C0C0C0;"><strong>Catégorie 2</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Check2</td>
                            <td>Oui</td>
                            <td>Oui</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Check2</td>
                            <td>Oui</td>
                            <td>Non</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Is it a static `<table>`? If it's the case, you just have to add an **empty** `<td></td>` before the "*avant*" `<td>`. Otherwise, could you provide a JsFiddle to help us helping you?

Comment: Code added in edit ;)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question, posting the answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to *hide* this extra `<th></th>` with for exemple

```
table thead tr th:first-child {
   background: none;
}
```

or with

```
/* Better if there is content in it, or if there is no background defined at start */

table thead tr th:first-child {
   opacity: 0; 
}
```

There is a few `CSS` ways to do this, but that's how I would do. Hope you got the idea.

As you already have some `inline CSS` and if you don't know how to deal with this `CSS`, you could also do it with the `inline CSS` way, even it's clearly less *clean* than the other ways.

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th style="opacity: 0;"></th>
    <th>Avant</th>
    <th>Aujourd'hui</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

**JsFiddle:**

`background: none;` solution: http://jsfiddle.net/5omkdhnu/1/

`opacity: 0;` solution: http://jsfiddle.net/5omkdhnu/2/

Comment: No, It's not that I search. I don't want to colspan 2 th, I want a result like this : http://perche.jeremy.free.fr/tab2.png (green is my body's background)

Comment: That's why I asked for a fiddle. : )   I'm editing my answer so.

Comment: @PokeRwOw Have a look now. Not really a generic code to *copy/pasta* here, but more an *idea* of how I would do. I don't know you level in `CSS` so once again, I hope you got the point to **adapt** this solution to your case.

Comment: @PokeRwOw Have you fixed your issue? If yes, could you *accept* this answer please?

Comment: Strangely, opacity and background:none doesn't work. But I can modify the bg-color of the cell...

Comment: As it's bootstrap, those values are probably already declared. An `!important` as `opacity: 0 !important;` to override this should do the trick?

Comment: Well, I can't help you more if you don't provide me any *URL* to have a look on, to inspect the code.